# Timer tick event not running

Tags: java, timer, task, render, lwjgl

I am writing a script that will cause the players HP to decrease at an interval as long as they are within a range of the item/monster/lava whatever it is. I have the detection just fine, but I cant seem to get the interval to run. I know this is probably because I am creating a new TimerTask as I render, but I cant seem to figure it out.

```
            for(Monster monster : monsters) {
            renderer.processEntity(monster);
            if(player.withinDistance(10, monster.getPosition()))
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("tick");
                    Player.PLAYER_HEALTH -= 10;

                }

            }, 2000, 2000);
        }
```

So for all monsters, it checks the positions, if you are near it opens a timer task that should tick every 2 seconds while that condition is true. How can I make this work properly? Is a timer task optimal for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are updating the `PLAYER_HEALTH` static property of the **Player class**. You should update the **Player instance**!

```
        for(Monster monster : monsters) {
        renderer.processEntity(monster);
        if(player.withinDistance(10, monster.getPosition()))
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("tick");
                player.decreaseHealth(10); // Use the instance

            }

        }, 2000, 2000);
    }
```

Also, if your program ends, the TimerTask will end too. Make sure your program is still running.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, and could have been one problem but my "tick" wasnt showing in the first place so Im thinking it has to do something with the way tick is being looped through. This function is in my main game loop

Comment: Should I be storing things like Player health, position, money, mana, exp and such properties as static references? Or should they just be normal globals that I set and save every time I open the program? U